# equivalentRate not matching for compounding cashflows

Tags: interest-rates, quantlib, compounding

> I am calculating equivalentrate between two days in quantlib python using following functions but the output is not matching with the manual calculation.

```
couponrate = ql.InterestRate(.0675, ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Compounded, ql.Monthly)
coupon = couponrate.equivalentRate(ql.Actual365Fixed(),ql.Compounded, ql.Quarterly,ql.Date(14,1,2020), ql.Date(14,4,2020)).rate()
print(coupon)
```

> 0.06788039941406243
>
> but correct equivalentRate value is 0.067879171338466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 91 days between January 14th and April 14th 2020, so the time between them is $T = 91/365$.

Given 1\$ today, a rate $r = 6.75\%$ compounded monthly over $T$ gives an amount $A = (1 + r/12)^{T \times 12}$, so:

```python
>>> import math
>>> T = 91/365
>>> r = 0.0675
>>> A = math.pow(1 + r/12, T*12)
>>> print(A)
1.0169232152238288
```

The rate that gives the same amount when compounded quarterly is $R$ such that $(1 + R/4)^{T \times 4} = A$, so $R = 4 \times (A^{1/(T \times 4)} - 1)$:

```python
>>> R = 4 * (math.pow(A, 1/(T*4)) - 1)
>>> print(R)
0.06788039941406243
```

You can check, of course, that this gives you the same compounded amount:

```
>>> print(math.pow(1 + R/4, T*4))
1.0169232152238288
```

How did you calculate your result?

Comment: Thank you @Luigi for your reply I have checked it from myside also,and would like to request you to go through my code. as for the same equivalentRate, I am getting different amount in quantlib which is 1.6923606429259497 and your value from above calculation is 1.0169232152238288 which is expected value. the code for this is as follows:

Comment: issuedate = ql.Date(14,1,2020)
maturitydate = ql.Date(14,4,2020)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Quarterly)
bussinessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Forward
settlementdays = 0
schedule = ql.Schedule(issuedate,maturitydate,tenor,ql.NullCalendar(),bussinessConvention,bussinessConvention,dateGeneration,False)
couponrates =0.06788039941406243(calulated as above)
leg = ql.FixedRateLeg(schedule,ql.Actual365Fixed(),[100],[couponrates])
bond = ql.Bond(settlementdays,ql.NullCalendar(),issuedate,leg)
print([c.amount() for c in bond.cashflows()])
[1.6923606429259497, 100.0]

Comment: Oh, so that's what you're trying to do.  Bond coupons are simple rates, not compounded (the formula for their compounding is just `1 + r * T`).  If you use `ql.Simple` in `equivalentRate` and pass the result to the bond you'll get a coupon amount of 1.692321522382878 as expected (which is `A-1`, because `A` includes the notional and the coupon only gives you the interest instead.)